# How can I configure apache 2 in ~/public_html on OpenSUSE 12.1

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, website, opensuse

I have OpenSUSE 12.1 installed. I tried a lot to get 
the lampp on the system workin.

i  set it up by YAST - (with the sheme-installations) how to get it working. How to configure the apache?

How can I set up apache2 in `~/public_html`?

btw: i have that file found:

```
#
# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.
#

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    # Note that the name of the user directory ("public_html") cannot easily be
    # changed here, since it is a compile time setting. The apache package
    # would have to be rebuilt. You could work around by deleting
    # /usr/sbin/suexec, but then all scripts from the directories would be
    # executed with the UID of the webserver.
    # 
    # To rebuild apache with another setting you need to change the 
    # %userdir define in the spec file. 

    # not every user's directory should be visible:
    UserDir disabled root

    # to enable UserDir only for a certain set of users, use this instead:
    #UserDir disabled
    #UserDir enabled user1 user2


    # the UserDir directive is actually used inside the virtual hosts, to 
    # have more control
    #UserDir public_html

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>

        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec

        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Limit>

        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>

    </Directory>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes - thx for editing

Comment: have this file found - see the initial posting

Comment: I think it should suffice to uncomment `#UserDir public_html`, then restart apache. But I'm no expert on this specific thing.

Comment: hi there - great to hear from you - will try to do so - greetings from europe